# Getting values inside an array to the database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

hi im trying to fill a database table from the code below, but afterwards it fills the table coloumn just saying "Array" is there anyway to get the values inside this array and make them print in the table.

```
$query_new = "INSERT INTO red_message (message) VALUES ('$attributes')";
$result = mysql_query($query_new, $link_local);
```

P.S i use the print_r once it returns 1.. so print_r diont work either.. can anybody help me to get the values inside this $attributes array

Comment: have you try to use `print_r($attributes)` before query get runs?

Comment: no.. wait ill try that as well

Comment: Your problem is that ```$attributes``` **is** an array and you're casting it to string. In PHP an array casted to a string is the string ```array```, you should use a function to transform the array into a meaningful string, for example ```implode```

Comment: its just returns 1 again

Comment: Are you using `echo print_r()`? If so, remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the `implode()`?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Example code from php.net:

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone
```

Comment: there is only one field. no need of `implode()`

Comment: Then he should print_r($attributes) to see what it contains.
Cuz he wrote it gives back an Array to him.

Answer (score 1):

try to use json_encode. If your array will be of several steps it is better to initially encode rhis array and then insert into the database. You also keep structure of the array.

Example:

```
$farr=array('user1'=>array('name'=>$name,'phone'=>$phone),'user2'=>array('name'=>$name,'phone'=>$phone));
$sarr=json_encode($farr);
mysql_query("Insert INTO .......");
```

After:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT ......");
$res=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$finaly=json_decode($res, true);
print_r($finaly);
```

Answer (score 1):

This simply means that `$attributes` is of `Array` type. You should make sure that `$attributes` is of `String` type (which you can achieve with `implode()`) before using it in  `mysql_query()`.